# Why does "split" on an empty string return a non-empty array?

Tags: java, scala

Split on an empty string returns an array of size 1 :

```
scala> "".split(',')
res1: Array[String] = Array("")
```

Consider that this returns empty array:

```
scala> ",,,,".split(',')
res2: Array[String] = Array()
```

Please explain :)

Comment: Additionally, it seems inconsistent with the behavior observed when the string contains only one instance of the separator. In this case the result is effectively an empty array: ",".split(",").length == 0

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For the same reason that

```
",test" split ','
```

and

```
",test," split ','
```

will return an array of size 2. Everything before the first match is returned as the first element.

Comment: @Nicklamort It seems self-evident to me, but you can look the Javadocs for `String`'s `split` if you need more information.

Comment: @Raphael Or in an Oracle database

Comment: @Raphael, in any other programming language `"".split("wtf").length` returns 0. Only in JS it's 1. :/

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Ok, so why `"," split ","` returns an array of 0 ?

Comment: @Joan That I cannot explain. The documentation for `split` does not seem to account for that.

Comment: Why isn't everything after the last match returned too?

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. This is why you are unable to answer @Joan's question.

Comment: @RokKralj Perhaps. I like your answer, but it is not based on split's javadoc. And I found the answer to Joan's question.

Comment: @Joan `split` without a second argument will discard all trailing empty strings. Since `"," split ","` doesn't have non-empty strings, everything in it is essentially a trailing empty string, which get discard.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: Yes, but then `"".split(",")` should be `Array()`, but it is `Array("")`, if it trims all rightmost strings. See now? :)

Comment: @RokKralj In that case there's nothing matching. And, according to the docs, `If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.`.

Comment: This isn't really an explanation so much as "here's examples". Was this a bug in an early Scala implementation, now baked into the spec since relied on by users? Or was this behavior purposefully decided? Is the trailing separator discard behavior in _any_ other language??

Comment: and the answer is it comes from java... So java is an example, perhaps the only example... Wild! I wonder why java chose this.

Answer (score 82):

If you split an orange zero times, you have exactly one piece - the orange.

Comment: But the orange isn't empty (idk if thats what oluies meant), its an orange. Maybe splitting an orange that should be there, but is not, so you get back a single value: an empty space xD

Comment: This is a deep conversation.

Comment: This metaphor makes sense for `"orange".split(',')`, but isn't obviously relevant for splitting empty strings. If I split my lack of orange zero times, I still have no orange; do we represent that as an empty list of no-oranges, a list of exactly one no-orange, a list of twelve no-oranges, or what? It's not a question of what we end up with, but how we represent it.

Comment: But if you split a non-existent book by its pages, you will get nothing.

Comment: Hm... what is `0/0`?

Answer (score 68):

The Java and Scala split methods operate in two steps like this:

- First, split the string by delimiter. The natural consequence is that if the string does not contain the delimiter, a singleton array containing just the input string is returned,
- Second, **remove all the rightmost empty strings.** This is the reason `",,,".split(",")` returns empty array.

According to this, the result of `"".split(",")` should be an empty array because of the second step, right?

**It should. Unfortunately, this is an artificially introduced corner case.** And that is bad, but at least it *is documented* in `java.util.regex.Pattern`, if you remember to take a look at the documentation:

> For n == 0, the result is as for n < 0, except trailing empty strings
>   will not be returned. **(Note that the case where the input is itself an
>   empty string is special, as described above, and the limit parameter
>   does not apply there.)**

## Solution 1: Always pass -1 as the second parameter

So, I advise you to always pass `n == -1` as the second parameter (this will skip step two above), unless you specifically know what you want to achieve / you are sure that the empty string is not something that your program would get as an input.

## Solution 2: Use Guava Splitter class

If you are already using Guava in your project, you can try the [Splitter (documentation)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class. It has a very rich API, and makes your code very easy to understand.

```
Splitter.on(".").split(".a.b.c.") // "", "a", "b", "c", ""
Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings().split("a,,b,,c") // "a", "b", "c"
Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf(",.")).split("a,b.c") // "a", "b", "c"
Splitter.onPattern("=>?").split("a=b=>c") // "a", "b", "c"
Splitter.on(",").limit(2).split("a,b,c") // "a", "b,c"
```

Comment: +1, this is the only answer that actually cites the documentation and points out that it is inconsistent. However, I did not find the highlighted part of the comment in my JavaDoc.

Comment: I have found it in java.util.regex.Pattern, but it seems to mostly be gone. At the time of writing, it definitely was present in the official OpenJDK source tree as a javadoc.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/ea021b608acfd0789d8751630575270dc4689630/regex/src/main/java/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#381

Maybe we should report a bug?

Comment: Would be a good idea to report a bug - the behaviour will definitely not be changed, but it should at least be documented.

Comment: @RokKralj Android did not use the OpenJDK library, but was instead based on Apache Harmony, so maybe you are looking in the wrong place?

Comment: What does "artificially introduced corner case" mean?

Comment: `"".split (",", n)` generates a one element array for n in (-1, 0, 1) with Oracle JDK 8.  Would be nice to get a list of non-empty tokens only -- guess a full regex may be necessary (something like `"[^,\\s]+[^,]*[^,\\s]*"`).

Answer (score 39):

Splitting an empty string returns the empty string as the first element. If no delimiter is found in the target string, you will get an array of size 1 that is holding the original string, even if it is empty.

Comment: Wrong. Split removes all the rightmost empty strings, therefore the result should be an empty array. See my answer.

`",".split(",")` returns empty array.

Answer (score 24):

`"a".split(",")` -> `"a"`
therefore
`"".split(",")` -> `""`

Comment: Wrong. Split removes all the rightmost empty strings, therefore the result should be an empty array. See my answer.

`",".split(",")` returns empty array.

Answer (score 5):

In all programming languages I know a blank string is still a valid String. So doing a split using any delimiter will always return a single element array where that element is the blank String. If it was a null (not blank) String then that would be a different issue.

Comment: I think this is a library function and not a part of the language. 
For example in google guava you could omit empty strings. 
>Iterable<String> pieces =  com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(',').omitEmptyStrings().split("");

Answer (score 2):

This [`split`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#split(x$1:String):Array[String]) behavior is inherited from Java, for better or worse...
Scala does not override the definition from the `String` primitive.

Note, that you can [use the `limit` argument to modify the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698765/1240268):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

i.e. you can set the `limit=-1` to get the behavior of (all?) other languages:

```
@ ",a,,b,,".split(",")
res1: Array[String] = Array("", "a", "", "b")

@ ",a,,b,,".split(",", -1)  // limit=-1
res2: Array[String] = Array("", "a", "", "b", "", "")
```

---

It's seems to be well-known the Java behavior is [quite confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21575526/1240268) but:

> The behavior above can be observed from at least Java 5 to Java 8.
>
> There was an attempt to change the behavior to return an empty array when splitting an empty string in [JDK-6559590](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6559590). However, it was soon reverted in [JDK-8028321](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028321) when it causes regression in various places. The change never makes it into the initial Java 8 release.

*Note: The split method wasn't in Java from the beginning (it's [not in 1.0.2](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/apibook/index.htm)) but actually is there from at least 1.4 (e.g. see [JSR51](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=51) circa 2002). I am still investigating...*

What's unclear is why Java chose this in the first place (my suspicion is that it was originally an oversight/bug in an "edge case"), but now irrevocably baked into the language and so [it remains](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2408).

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question - while it may be true for the example given here, it doesn't help with the case of the empty string - `"".split(",")` still returns a single element array like `[""]`.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave that's expected behavior of every other language. The ",,,," is the bizarre/different behavior in Scala, and disparate to the "" case.

Answer (score 0):

Empty string have no special status while splitting a string. You may use:

```
Some(str)
  .filter(_ != "")
  .map(_.split(","))
  .getOrElse(Array())
```

Answer (score 0):

use this Function,

```
public static ArrayList<String> split(String body) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Optional.ofNullable(body).filter(a->!a.isEmpty()).orElse(",").split(",")));
}
```