# In clojure why does splitting a string from an empty file return 1 element?

Tags: file-io, vector, clojure, string

Consider the following:

```
=> (even? (count []))
true
```

so far so good. Now consider (assume my-file is empty):

```
(odd? (count (str/split (slurp my-file) #"\|")))
true
```

err ... why is the vector returned from an empty file not even (zero) ?

```
=>(str/split (slurp my-file) #"\|")
[""]
```

Ahh, can someone explain why an empty string is returned in this case?

I'm attempting to determine if there are an odd number of records in a file or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`clojure.string/split` uses `java.util.regex.Pattern/split` to do the splitting.  See [this question about Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array) for explanation.  Namely, `split` returns everything before the first match of your pattern as the first split, even if the pattern doesn't match at all.

The canonical way to test if a collection (list,array,map,string etc.) is empty or not is to call `seq` on it, which will return `nil` for an empty collection.

```
(defn odd-number-of-records? [filename]
  (let [txt (slurp filename)]
    (when (seq txt)
      (odd? (count (str/split txt #"\|"))))))
```

Comment: In this case one may also simply check the count of the input string. `(let [...] (when (pos? (count txt)) ...))` I find this a bit cleaner, because it doesn't unnecessarily allocate a seq object which is thrown away immediatelly. `seq` on a data structure is expensive compared to `count`.