# String split behaviour on empty string and on single delimiter string

Tags: java, scala

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array).

The question is on the second line below.

```
"".split("x");   //returns {""}   // ok
"x".split("x");  //returns {}   but shouldn't it return {""} because it's the string before "x" ?
"xa".split("x"); //returns {"", "a"}    // see?, here "" is the first string returned
"ax".split("x"); //returns {"a"}
```

Comment: see [SI-5096](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5069) "Bug in split() when delimiters occur at end of string"

Comment: This is why Google Guava created com.google.common.base.Splitter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the `java.util.regex.Pattern` [source](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/regex/Pattern.java.htm#splitCharSequenceint), which `String.split(..)` uses,

```
"".split("x");   // returns {""} - valid - when no match is found, return the original string
"x".split("x");  // returns {} - valid - trailing empty strings are removed from the resultant array {"", ""}
"xa".split("x"); // returns {"", "a"} - valid - only trailing empty strings are removed
"ax".split("x"); // returns {"a"} - valid - trailing empty strings are removed from the resultant array {"a", ""}
```

Comment: so it behaves correctly because the method it calls...behaves that way? I wonder what my boss will say when I close the next bug report with an argument like that.

Comment: @Kim Stebel, neither `SO` is a bugtracker, nor am I supposed to fix bugs for it. This post basically asked for clarification, and not a solution, and I simply tried to present why the `split` method is behaving that way. take it easy.

Answer (score 7):

No, because according to [the relevant javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) "trailing empty strings will be discarded".

Comment: Then why isn't it discarded in the first line? (Splitting on empty String)

Comment: This should be understood as "empty strings at the end of the resulting array will be discarded".

Comment: I guess it sees the empty string as the first token, then splits after it, so technically it's a leading empty string

Comment: Again, from the JavaDoc: "If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string." Maybe it's not consistent but it works as promised.

Answer (score 0):

To include the trailing empty strings, use the other implementation of [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-).

```
"".split("x", -1);   // returns {""} - valid - when no match is found, return the original string
"x".split("x", -1);  // returns {"", ""} - valid - trailing empty strings are included in the resultant array {"", ""}
"xa".split("x", -1); // returns {"", "a"} - valid
"ax".split("x", -1); // returns {"a", ""} - valid - trailing empty strings are included in the resultant array {"a", ""}
```