# Java String's split method ignores empty substrings

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, split

It occured to me today the behavior of java `String.split()` is very strange.

Actually I want to split a string `"aa,bb,cc,dd,,,ee"` to array by `.split(",")` that gives me a String array `["aa","bb","cc","dd","","","ee"]` of length 7.

But when I try to split a String `"aa,bb,cc,dd,,,,"` to array this gives me a array of length 4 means only `["aa","bb","cc","dd"]` rejecting all next blank Strings.

I want a procedure that splits a String like `"aa,bb,cc,dd,,,,"` to array `["aa","bb","cc","dd","","",""]`.

Is this possible with java.lang.String api? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with negative limit (e.g. -1).

```
"aa,bb,cc,dd,,,,".split(",", -1)
```

When [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is called, it is called with `limit` = 0, which will remove all trailing empty strings in the array (in most cases, see below).

The actual behavior of `String.split(String regex)` is quite confusing:

- Splitting an empty string will result in an array of length 1. *Empty string split will always result in length 1 array containing the empty string*.
- Splitting `";"` or `";;;"` with `regex` being `";"` will result in an empty array. *Non-empty string split will result in all trailing empty strings in the array removed*.

The behavior above can be observed from at least Java 5 to Java 8.

There was an attempt to change the behavior to return an empty array when splitting an empty string in [JDK-6559590](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6559590). However, it was soon reverted in [JDK-8028321](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028321) when it causes regression in various places. The change never makes it into the initial Java 8 release.

Comment: This is not working for me: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)

Comment: This is wild...!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`public String[] split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The `limit` parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

---

```
String st = "aa,bb,cc,dd,,,,";
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(st.split(",",-1)));
                                                    ↑
```

Prints:

```
[aa, bb, cc, dd, , , , ]
```