# Meaning of 2nd parameter in StringOps.split(String, Int)

Tags: scala

I was trying to split a string and keep the empty strings. Fortunately i found a promising solution which gave me my expected results as following REPL session depicts:

```
scala> val test = ";;".split(";",-1)
test: Array[String] = Array("", "", "")
```

I was curious what the second parameter actually does and dived into the [scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) but found nothing except this:

[image]

Also inside the REPL interpreter i only get the following information:

```
scala> "asdf".split
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
def split(String): Array[String]        
def split(String, Int): Array[String]
```

**Question**
Does anybody have an alternate source of documentation for such badly documented parameters?
Or can someone explain what this 2dn parameter does on this specific function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the same `split` from `java.lang.String`, which as it so happens, has better [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Comment: The quantity of n does only matter when being positive, if i understand the documentation correctly. Thus any negative amount will result in the same output though `-1` can be replaced by any negative number. Am i right?