# _str is not defined while using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is the first time I am using Underscore.js. I have included the production `underscore-min.js` at the bottom of my page ( which is in Jade originally ), just before my custom script.

```
<script src="/javascripts/underscore-min.js">
<script src="/javascripts/custom.js">
```

Now, I call this function in my `custom.js`:

```
var selections = "Bold;Business-like;Charming";
var num_selections = _str.words( question.selected_words, ";").length;
```

Basically, I need to know the number of words selected and the native javascript method `split` returns 1 for even a blank string. But when I use this code, I get this error in my browser console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: _str is not defined`

I tried using this line before using `_str`, but then I get `require is not defined`:

```
var _  = require('underscore');
```

Or, perhaps I can put my question as **How do we start using underscore functions in our front-end javascripts**?

Comment: Are you using node? require is a node.js function.

Comment: @Jordan Yes, I'm using node.js but this error is coming on front-end. I need to use `_str` function in my front-end javascript.

Comment: So the variable ***selections*** is the reference for the data that you are looking to get the total?

Comment: @OverflowStack `selections` is a semi-colon delimited string of multiple words. I need to know how many words there are.

Comment: When using ***split()*** did you try testing for empty string first?

Comment: @OverflowStack No, you're right. That solves my current problem, thanks :). Still I do not know why I could not use underscore functions.

Comment: The underscore function you are attempting to use {_.words} is a member of the ***Underscore.String*** library and not the ***Underscore.JS*** library.  Additionally, you will need to install via your Node.JS via NPM like this

Comment: The underscore function you are attempting to use **_.words** is a member of the ***Underscore.String*** library and not the ***Underscore.JS*** library.  Additionally, you will need to install via NPM in Node.JS interpreter ($ npm install underscore.string).

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using node, require is not available on the front-end. Front-end javascript is not the same as back-end, nor do they directly interact. Underscore is called using `_`. All the methods available here: http://underscorejs.org/ are accessed via `_.<method_name>`. I am not too familiar with underscore and maybe you are using an older version but I cannot find `_.str` anywhere in the docs. So first, make sure you are using the correct notation for underscore `_.<method_name>` and make sure the function exists in the documentation. This fiddle shows some basic underscore functions: https://jsfiddle.net/mawpw2c5/

Comment: I think you're right. I was trying to follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516370/javascript-split-gives-array-size-one-instead-of-zero-for-empty-string but now I think that references a new library underscore.string module.