# Array Split null value counting 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript array lengh giving 1 if null.I am using Split function.

```
var str = '';
var arr = str.split(',');
alert(arr.length);
**Output:1**
```

When there is any value in string counting correctly

```
  var str = 'a,b,c';
  var arr = str.split(',');
  alert(arr.length);
  ****Output:3****
```

Comment: You can wrap it into an if statement:

    var str = '';
    
    if (str) {
      var arr = str.split(',');
    } else  {
      var arr = [];
    }

    alert(arr.length);

This way you will have an evaluation of your string and since empty string evaluates to `falsy` in JS, you will run the else statement when the string is empty returning an empty array.

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516370/javascript-split-gives-array-size-one-instead-of-zero-for-empty-string Other one was for Scala. Not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string isn't a *null value*. And `String.prototype.split` splits a string into array indexes when it finds the separator character. In your empty string, there's a *single string*. Therefore, you get an array length of `1`.

Comment: ok.then how i can calculate string length in array?

Comment: @Raju Elaborate more on this please, I don't understand your question at all...

Comment: @Raju Do you mean this? `var totalLength = array.reduce(function(result, str) { result += str.length; return result; }, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

when you do 
    var arr = str.split(',');
the returned array is not null. It has one element and that value has space in it.
So when you do arr.length - it will return 1 as it has one element and that element is space " ".

Hope it helps.
Happy Learning :)