# Groovy Truthy question: String.split() produces empty array, but is 'true' ? How?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Below is a series of steps I have taken in the grooysh shell demonstrate the problem

`String.split()` => `String[]` as expected in the Java SDK. When I evaluate this as part of a continuing expression: `changedDirs.split('\r\n').collect{ ... }` my `collect` executes 1 time with an empty `it`. Let me grant: this code is running on a Jenkins server and Jenkins is known to have, let's say, a *dialect* of groovy running. But, regardless, when I test it locally with groovysh, I indeed get something I didn't expect: `[]` evaluates to `truthy` *if* it comes from `String.split()`

So: Can someone explain:

1. How this groovy code below produces a `truthy` for `String.split()` and not for a basic empty `[]`
2. Is Jenkins doing something weird?

```
groovy:000> [] ? 'true' : 'false'
===> false
groovy:000> changedDirs = ''
===> 
groovy:000> changedDirs.split('\r\n')
===> []
groovy:000> changedDirs.split('\r\n') ? true : false
===> true
groovy:000> result = changedDirs.split('\r\n')
===> []
groovy:000> result ? true : false
===> true
groovy:000> result.class
===> class [Ljava.lang.String;
groovy:000> [] as String[] ? true : false
===> false
groovy:000>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `result` evaluates to `true` as boolean, because `changedDirs.split('\r\n')` produces `String[]` array with a single element - an empty string. Take a look at the following example:

```
groovy:000> ([] as String[]).class
===> class [Ljava.lang.String;
groovy:000> ([] as String[]) ? true : false
===> false
groovy:000> x = ([] as String[])
===> []
groovy:000> x.dump()
===> <[Ljava.lang.String;@5c41d037>
groovy:000> y = "".split(",")
===> []
groovy:000> y.class
===> class [Ljava.lang.String;
groovy:000> y.dump()
===> <[Ljava.lang.String;@79a1728c>
groovy:000> y ? true : false
===> true
groovy:000> y.length
===> 1
groovy:000> x.length
===> 0
groovy:000> y[0].dump()
===> <java.lang.String@0 value= hash=0>
groovy:000>
```

In the "Groovy Truth", every non-empty array evaluates to `true` when calls `asBoolean()` method, no matter what is the value of the elements in the array.

If you look at the following Java code example, you will see that `String.split(pattern)` method produces a single element array in case of an empty string.

```java
final class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = "".split("\r\n");

        System.out.println(array.length); // prints: 1
    }
}
```

This SO question might be useful - [Why does "split" on an empty string return a non-empty array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array)

Comment: `.inspect()` illustrates the problem better than `.dump()`

Comment: Here is what I did: `(changedDirs ?: null)?.split('\r\n')` and this produces what I want. Man, even when you thought you knew a lot...