# cannot call items.isEmpty() after splitting an array

Tags: java, string, split, trim, is-empty

I am a beginner. Why `isEmpty()` is defined an error in my question.

I trim and split a string array:

```
String[] items = s.trim().split("[ !,?.\\_'@]+");
```

I want to print

```
int i = (items.isEmpty()) ? 0 : items.length;
```

but `isEmpty` shows an error.

Comment: Because there is no `isEmpty()` method for an array. And you don't need one; you can just use `int i = items.length`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays don't have `isEmpty` method. You need to check it yourself with `items.length == 0`.

Also, be aware that `items` is never empty:

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

Comment: Can i make a string and trim it then another string array split here and then can i use isEmpty for string and print length of array

Comment: @Harry what do you want to check? If the string has been split?

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried and print length of String Array.

Answer (score 1):

`String[] items` is known as an `array` and is one of the most simple `data structures` in Java. There are more complicated and handy data structures like `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, etc.

The `isEmpty()` is a method which has been declared in [the List Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty--), so all the Java classes that implemented this interface have their implementation of `isEmpty` method. (`String[]` **is not** an implementation of `List`)

Note: split method always returns [a non-empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array/16013594), so it is useless to to have a method like `isEmpty`. You can just check the length of returned value, `items.length == 0`