# "number of segments in a string" not working for a particular input

Tags: java, string

I have to find "contiguous sequence of non-space characters" in a string.
My output is coming wrong for the input

```
Input=", , , ,        a, eaefa"
```

My answer is coming as 13 instead of 6.Though I have only counted words except for spaces.

```
class Solution {
    public int countSegments(String s) 
    {
        if(s.isEmpty()){
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int count=0;
            String s1[]=s.split(" ");
            for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
            {
                if(s1[i]!=" ")
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.equals` instead of `!=` for String comparison

Comment: SirRaffleBuffle's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61578048/11882002) is better than mine, you probably want to accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use split on multiple spaces, and then you have the segments already divided up for you, so you don't need to make a for-loop or anything.

```
//The trim is because split gets messed up with leading spaces, as SirRaffleBuffle said
s = s.trim();
if (s.isEmpty()) return 0;
return s.split("\\s+").length;
```

- If you want only sequences of *alphanumeric* characters, you can try this regex instead: `"\\W+"`
- If you want only sequences of English letters, you can do the same thing but with the regex `"[^A-Za-z]+"`.

Here, it splits on multiple spaces instead of just one.

The way you're currently doing it, you count every single letter that's not a whitespace instead of "contiguous sequences of no-space characters". That's why you're getting 13 instead of 6.

Notice that count is incremented anytime it finds something that isn't a space, but if you do want to do this with a for-loop, you should have a boolean flag telling you that you've entered a sequence, so you only increment count when that flat was previously false (you were outside a sequence) and then you find a space.

Also, using `!=` for String comparison is wrong, you should use the `equals` method.

Comment: This fails on strings with leading spaces e.g. " a" returns 2.

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle Thank you, I've edited my answer to reflect that and the fact that splitting on empty strings returns a non-empty array now

Comment: The trouble with this is that it will return 1 for a string containing only spaces, as this will be reduced to the empty string. The fix is to check for the empty string *after* calling `trim()` but before calling `split()`.

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle you're absolutely right yet again. I'm going to ask the OP to accept your answer

Comment: No problem, for me this site is all about learning. Your answer is now fine.

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggesting using:

```
s.split("\\s+").length
```

However, there are [complications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array/16013594) in using `split`. Specifically, the above will give incorrect answers for strings with leading spaces. Even if these issues are fixed it's still overly expensive as we're creating `count` new strings, and an array to hold them.

We can implement `countSegments` directly by iterating through the string and counting the number of times we go from a non-space character to a space character, or the end of the string:

```
public static int countSegments(String s)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=s.length(); i++)
    {
        if((s.charAt(i-1) != ' ') && (i == s.length() || s.charAt(i) == ' ')) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Test:

```
for(String s : new String[] {"", " ", "a", " a", "a ", " a ", ", , , ,        a, eaefa"})
    System.out.format("<%s> : %d%n", s, countSegments(s));
```

Output:

```
<> : 0
< > : 0
<a> : 1
< a> : 1
<a > : 1
< a > : 1
<, , , ,        a, eaefa> : 6
```

Answer (score 1):

> **“number of segments in a string”** not working for a particular input

You can do it easily by using the regex, `\\s+` as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = ", , , ,        a, eaefa";
        str = str.trim();// Remove the leading and trailing space
        System.out.println(str.isEmpty() ? 0 : str.split("\\s+").length);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

The regex, `\\s+` matches on one or more consecutive spaces.

On a side note, you are using `!=` to compare strings, which is not correct. Note that `==` and `!=` are used to compare the references, not the values.

Comment: This fails on strings with leading spaces e.g. " a" returns 2. It also returns 1 for the empty string.

Comment: Thank you. I've rectified the problem now.