# size function applied to empty array column in dataframe returns 1 after spilt

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

Noticed that with `size` function on an array column in a dataframe using following code - which includes a `split`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{trim, explode, split, size}

val df1 = Seq(
  (1, "[{a},{b},{c}]"),
  (2, "[]"),
  (3, "[{d},{e},{f}]")
).toDF("col1", "col2")
df1.show(false)

val df2 = df.withColumn("cola", split(trim($"col2", "[]"), ",")).withColumn("s", size($"cola"))
df2.show(false)
```

we get:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+---+
|col1|col2         |cola           |s  |
+----+-------------+---------------+---+
|1   |[{a},{b},{c}]|[{a}, {b}, {c}]|3  |
|2   |[]           |[]             |1  |
|3   |[{d},{e},{f}]|[{d}, {e}, {f}]|3  |
+----+-------------+---------------+---+
```

I was hoping for a zero so as to be able distinguish between 0 or 1 entries.

A few hints here and there on SO, but none that helped.

If I have the following entry:   `(2, null)`, then I get size -1, which is more helpful I guess.

On the other hand, this borrowed sample from the internet:

```
val df = Seq("a" -> Array(1,2,3), "b" -> null, "c" -> Array(7,8,9)).toDF("id","numbers")
df.show
val df2 = df.withColumn("numbers", coalesce($"numbers", array()))
df2.show
val df3 = df2.withColumn("s", size($"numbers"))
df3.show()
```

does return 0 - as expected.

> Looking for the correct approach here so as to get size = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the root cause is that `split` returns an empty string, instead of a null.

```
scala> df1.withColumn("cola", split(trim($"col2", "[]"), ",")).withColumn("s", $"cola"(0)).select("s").collect()(1)(0)
res53: Any = ""
```

And the size of an array containing an empty string is, of course, 1.

To get around this, perhaps you could do

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("cola", split(trim($"col2", "[]"), ","))
             .withColumn("s", when(length($"cola"(0)) =!= 0, size($"cola"))
                              .otherwise(lit(0)))

df2.show(false)
+----+-------------+---------------+---+
|col1|col2         |cola           |s  |
+----+-------------+---------------+---+
|1   |[{a},{b},{c}]|[{a}, {b}, {c}]|3  |
|2   |[]           |[]             |0  |
|3   |[{d},{e},{f}]|[{d}, {e}, {f}]|3  |
+----+-------------+---------------+---+
```

Comment: Well, suppose? i think it is a fair observation. Agree?

Comment: Yes, I think string operations never returns null if you started with anything non-null

Comment: Well i studied string packages with pascal at uni in the 80's and a null outcome was possible.

Comment: that's classic stuff! ;)

Comment: I am going for the answer although I am not convinced a good implementation.

Comment: Of course I could have done the solution myself...Anyway I think u r breaking the record for 10K! HNY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226732/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-mck).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is inherited from the [Java function split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split-java.lang.CharSequence-int-) which is used in the same way in Scala and Spark. The empty input is a special case, and this is well discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array).

Spark sets the [default value](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/bd346f4a2d078dd36d2fcadf3d5025389b124814/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2729) for the second parameter (`limit`) of the `split` function to **-1**. And as of Spark 3, we can now pass a limit parameter for [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#split) function.

You can see this in Scala split function vs Spark SQL split function:

```scala
"".split(",").length
//res31: Int = 1

spark.sql("""select size(split("", '[,]'))""").show
//+----------------------+
//|size(split(, [,], -1))|
//+----------------------+
//|                     1|
//+----------------------+
```

And

```scala
",".split(",").length // without setting limit=-1 this gives empty array
//res33: Int = 0

",".split(",", -1).length
//res34: Int = 2

spark.sql("""select size(split(",", '[,]'))""").show
//+-----------------------+
//|size(split(,, [,], -1))|
//+-----------------------+
//|                      2|
//+-----------------------+
```